# What are the Steps to use google & twitter login plugin for registration in asp.net web application c# 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, user-registration

Hey i am developing a asp.net web application.I need to know to how can i use google registration for making users register into my site. For that i need to fetch basic info like name,email,dob, gender,location etc. I was able to fetch facebook info.But i am stuck at collecting info from google.Can anybody tel me the basic steps needed to get the basic info from google.How to use the api?or please direct me to some useful links so that i can get a clear cut idea?My working platform is asp.net C# 2008.Framework version is 3.5. It will be very helpful if any suggestion/example from framwork 3.5...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried DotNetOpenAuth?

Tutorial : http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/programmatic-openid-relying-party/
Example : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef/

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for ur answer.I am not familiar with mvc and my current work atmosphere is not allowing framwork 4.0 .Any suggestion with 3.5??Thanks in advance

Comment: MVC, a design pattern, does not mean that you need to use .NET 4.0 (mvc 1,2 and 3), it can be used also in .NET 3.5 (mvc 1 and 2).Even that If you are using standar web-forms in the first example you can find a solution.